# bxslider not working properly for dynamically loaded content

Tags: bxslider

Had to use bxslider for one of the app. I have some issues while trying to implement bxslider with dynamically loaded content over ajax.

It works abruptly. Interestingly when there is a slight change in view port either by opening dev tools or window size change, it does *sometime works*.

Would just like to understand has anyone faced this issue before and what could be the workaround.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BxSlider now contains two new methods:

- `reloadSlider()`
- `destroySlider()`

After loading new content into your slider, try calling `reloadSlider()`, as this will re-initialize the slider and accomodate the new slides.

Check here for code examples:

- http://bxslider.com/examples/reload-slider
- http://bxslider.com/examples/reload-slider-settings

Comment: This helped me fix the problem, thanks! I put it inside of a $(window).resize(function() {});