# how to get bxslider to work with instafeed.js

Tags: jquery, instagram, bxslider

I am currently working on a project that is pulling instagram pictures using instafeedjs but wanted to use bxslider to have it show like a slideshow and fade.

I noticed that since the images are being dynamically loaded, bxslider isn't really applied properly.

I know that there is a function for bxslider to reload slider option
(http://bxslider.com/examples/reload-slider) but i'm not quote shore how to get it to reload right after the page is loaded rather than onclick as in their example.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Can you provide your code in a jsFiddle?

Comment: hi @r3mus I'm not sure how I can put this in jsFiddle since it's dynamic content. Perhaps I can show you a link instead?

Comment: Sure, anything to go on. Without more info, no one will be able to help ;)

Comment: Where on the page am I looking?

Comment: @r3mus, it's near the top. it's these square images that are flashing (that's the feed itself) next to the copy block that says "our kakaako is a commitment"

Comment: Have you tried initiating it on `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: I tried putting this script in var mySlider;
    $(function(){
     mySlider= $('.slider-instagram').bxSlider({
      mode: 'fade',
      auto: true,
      pause: 2000,
      speed: 3000
     });
    });
   
    $(function(){
     mySlider.reloadSlider();
    }); but it wouldn't work I think because the images just got loaded dynamically?

any chance you have google chat or something @r3mus?

Comment: Don't have google chat- but looking at your source, line 587 has jQuery(document).ready, and line 629 does too, where you appear to actually be triggering the bxslider. Take everything for it out of .bind('inview') and just move it under $(document).ready()

Comment: @r3mus, i tried that but it doesn't work

Comment: Get rid of the $(function wrapper and just use `$('.slider-instagram').bxSlider({
     mode: 'fade',
     auto: true,
     pause: 2000,
     speed: 3000
    });`, per their very basic example on http://bxslider.com/

Comment: @r3mus, I tried that too but it still doesn't work. I think it's because the instagram pictures are being dynamically loaded so it doesn't let me apply the bxslider. The fix i saw from (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14196358/bxslider-not-working-properly-for-dynamically-loaded-content) was to use the reload option but that's why I did it in the (.bind("inview")) section because I didn't know how else to call it without using an onClick function. Sorry, am I thinking this through wrong?

Comment: Maybe you're overthinking it yeah, but using the 'inview' event is going to cause you MAJOR grief -- if you look at the CPU usage of your browser once it loads, you'll see it effectively cripples performance. Sorry I couldn't be of more help -- I think your best bet is to try and separate it from the website you're working and sandbox it in jsFiddle. If you can get it working there, it'll be easier to port it to the site.

Comment: @r3mus, yeah. =\ thanks for trying to help me! I really appreciate it! So the only other way to call something without using an event listener like onClick is to use document ready, correct?

Comment: Oh there are several events - document.ready will load it once the page renders, but others here: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/

Comment: @r3mus, yah I'm such a newbie at this jQuery stuff. All of those look very intimidating! Which one of those would I use to say, after the page has loaded, then reload the slider?

Comment: document.ready is the best because it will initiate the animation once the page has loaded, but won't fire again.

Comment: @r3mus, right. Shucks! Then technically it should work so I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: That's why I'm suggesting you try and get just the Instagram part working in jsFiddle. If you get it working there, you'll be able to port it over a lot easier.